# How to use a trait type as an argument to an optionally compiled member function of a class template?

Tags: g++, c++20, clang++, c++-concepts

I would like to define a member function in a class template only if traits contain `type` and use `type` as its argument like that:

```
struct A {};
struct B { using type = int; };

template <typename T>
concept has_type = requires { typename T::type; };

template <typename Traits>
struct Handler
{
    void set(typename Traits::type)
        requires has_type<Traits>
    {}
};
```

Unfortunately, `typename Traits::type` is parsed before the `requires` clause and it fails to compile if `type` does not exist (`struct A`):

```
<source>:19:14: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct A'
   19 |         void set(typename Traits::type)
```

I could only come up with this alternative, which looks excessively cumbersome:

```
template <typename Traits>
struct Handler
{
    template <typename Type>
        requires has_type<Traits> && std::same_as<Type, typename Traits::type>
    void set(Type)
    {}
};
```

It also fails to compile under clang (although I expected it to short-circuit), but gcc compiles it correctly:

```
<source>:20:78: error: no type named 'type' in 'A'
            requires has_type<Traits> && std::same_as<Type, typename Traits::type>
```

[Full example](https://godbolt.org/z/hqrrh6zan).

**Questions**

1. What is the idiomatic way to define `set` depending on whether `Traits` class contains `type`?
2. Why does clang try to evaluate `std::same_as` if `requires has_type` failed?
3. Who is right, clang or gcc?

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/44178

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A class template member function is constrainable, but is not SFINAE-aware.  The idiomatic solution (which, inter alia, works even under C++17) is to make `set` a (class template member) function template accessing the `type` member type alias via (type-dependent) SFINAE context:

```
template<int..., class U = Traits>
void set(typename U::type);
```

or:

```
template<std::same_as<Traits> U = Traits>
void set(typename U::type);
```

[Example](https://godbolt.org/z/3Mx6EW4fx).

wrt 2., 3., see [How to use a trait type as an argument to an optionally compiled member function of a class template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73741544/how-to-use-a-trait-type-as-an-argument-to-an-optionally-compiled-member-function/73742281#comment130215082_73741544)